# How Can I convert infix expression containing ++ or -- to a normal infix expression

Tags: expression, c-strings, infix-notation

Basically, I'm trying to get rid of ++ or -- from an infix expression by incrementing the value that's applied to it, but the code gives a weird output. I also used a shifting function to delete the ++ or --.

for example:

-infix before: 1++-4/5

-infix after: 2-4/5

-my program outputs: ,-4/5/5

Here's my code(contains only functions relevant to the problem):

```
void shift(int i, int j, char expression[])
{
    for (int k = i + 1; k < strlen(expression); k++)
    {
        expression[j++] = expression[k];
    }
}
void unary_to_normal(char expression[])
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(expression); i++)
    {
        // for ++
        if (expression[j] == expression[i] && expression[j] == '+')
        {   //char to int
            int integer = (expression[j] - '0') + 1;
            //int to char
            expression[j - 1] = integer + '0';
            shift(i, j, expression);
        }
        // for --
        if (expression[j] == expression[i] && expression[j] == '-')
        {   //converting char to int
            int integer = (expression[j] - '0') + 1;
            //int to char
            expression[j - 1] = integer + '0';
            shift(i, j, expression);
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the general idea but I'm not sure I completely understand what's going on in your code. From what you posted I believe I see a few issues:

###### major: `if` code blocks

In the code inside the `if` blocks:

```c
            int integer = (expression[j] - '0') + 1;
            //int to char
            expression[j - 1] = integer + '0';
            shift(i, j, expression);
```

For that code to be reached, `expression[j]` should be `'+'` or `'-'`. What exactly are you trying to achieve with the `integer` declaration? That'll result in either `-4` or `-2` ([ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/)). In turn, the operand over which it was acting (`expression[j - 1]`) will be converted into `,` (44 integer) or `.` (46 integer).

Based on your initial example (`1++-4/5`) I'd expect you wanted to do something like the following instead:

```c
            expression[j - 1]++;
            shift(i, j, expression);
```

Mind there'll still be pitfalls with that code. It won't cover the "overflow" from `9` to `10`.

Given the initial code I'm assuming you were ok with that. If that's not the case you'll need to solve for these issues as well.

###### major: `for --` adding instead of subtracting

In the `for --` `if` block you should be subtracting `1` instead of adding. Considering the previous item it should be something like:

```c
            expression[j - 1]--;
            shift(i, j, expression);
```

Mind the "underflow" in case the `--` operand is `0` (or any number that ends in `0`) won't be covered.

###### major: `shift` function loop

The `strlen` function returns the number of characters in a null-terminated string. It **doesn't** include the null-terminator itself. That's why you're getting the `/5/5` repetition at the end of the final string.

One way of fixing it would be making the `for` loop run until `k <= strlen(expression)`. That way you'd be copying the null-terminator as well.

###### unsure: `--` and `++` operators logic

This might not be an issue to the logic you're trying to implement but there's a very important difference to where these operators are located in C. If they prepend the operand (e.g. `++x`), the operator is first applied and, only after that, the expression is evaluated. The order is reversed if the operator is inserted after the operand (e.g. `x++`).

For instance, the following expressions evaluate to different values:

- `int x = 1; x++-4;`, in C, will result in `-3`
- `int x = 1; ++x-4;`, in C, will result in `-2`

If that's irrelevant to your expression parser you can safely ignore this section.

###### minor: micro-optimizing the `for` loop in the `unary_to_normal` function

Instead of handling the `j` variable manually you can manage it in the `for` loop alongside `i`. The following is perfectly valid:

`for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < strlen(expression); i++, j++)`

Unless you have a reason **not** to increase `j` in every loop iteration you should consider having the `for` loop handle it instead of doing it manually. That's less likely to lead to errors and it makes your intention clearer to other readers.

---

A working version (considering the caveats that were previously mentioned) would look something like the following:

```c
void shift(int i, int j, char expression[])
{
    for (int k = i + 1; k <= strlen(expression); k++)
    {
        expression[j++] = expression[k];
    }
}
void unary_to_normal(char expression[])
{
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < strlen(expression); i++, j++)
    {
        // for ++
        if (expression[j] == expression[i] && expression[j] == '+')
        {
            expression[j - 1]++;
            shift(i, j, expression);
        }
        // for --
        if (expression[j] == expression[i] && expression[j] == '-')
        {
            expression[j - 1]--;
            shift(i, j, expression);
        }
    }
}
```

For these functions, an input expression `1++-4/5` is converted to `2-4/5`. `1---4/5` is converted to `0-4/5`.